# ~ no response on stdout ~ C# Error while submitting code in HackerRank

Tags: c#, stdout, console.writeline

I am practicing C# code on HackerRank online website, when I want to submit my code then it gives an error:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<input.Count-1;i++){
        string evenData="",oddData="";
        string data=input[i];
        for(int j=0;j<data.Length-1;j++){
            
            if(i%2==0){
                evenData += data[j].ToString();
            }else{
                oddData +=data[j].ToString();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(evenData + " " +oddData);
    }
```

I have already search over the internet for this issue but everyone says just add **Console.WriteLine** because stdout and Console.writeLine both are just like same but it doesn't resolve my problem.
Kindly provide me a better solution.
Thanks

Comment: Use visual studio code or visual studio to debug this code. That's what we will also do. Learn basics of array and for loop also.

Comment: Are you sure you want those "-1" parts in the loop iteration? That means you're ignoring the last element of `input` and `data`, and that seems unlikely to be desirable.

Comment: Yes because I want to show data in reversible order

Comment: did u got the solution,i am facing same issue with c#

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.In.ReadLine() and Console.Out.WriteLine() for stdin and stdout.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    
    public static void Result(string s)
    {
        var sarry = s.ToCharArray();
        if(sarry.Length >1)
        {
            var evenstr = "";
            var oddstr  = "";
            
            for(int i=0 ;i<=sarry.Length-1 ; i++)
            {
                if(i%2==0)
                    oddstr=oddstr+sarry[i];
                else
                    evenstr=evenstr+sarry[i];
            }
            var result =oddstr+" "+evenstr;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(result);            
        }
    }
    
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        
        int T=int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) 
        {
            var inp=Console.In.ReadLine();
            Solution.Result(inp);
        }
    }
}
```